# VBA Code - Advanced Filter: Summarize Data from one sheet to another sheet via one button click

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to create a function [Summarize Data] that can summarize information from one sheet, presenting it in a specific format on another sheet.

The datasheet (Follow-up Schedule) is ever-changing, as new entries get added by the click of a button (already have this working, see Follow-Up Schedule below).

- *Follow-Up Schedule* [image: Follow-Up Schedule]

What I would like to do is create a table that will update every time you click on a button (Generate Summary) and will also count the results of every finding (see Summary Page below).

- *Summary Page* [image: Summary Page]

In conclusion:

- I need it to count every unique Company and present it on the list
- It has to count the total number of Findings per unique company
- It has to put those total findings in the respective category/column (eg. Resolved)
- It has to add the total row and percentages at the end of the information at the bottom

How do I do the above and Summarize Data from one sheet to another via a single button click?

Please help by providing me with the code to Create a VBA for a button that goes through your data and tallies the cells and presents in the summary table. A non-VBA approach/solution would also be helpful.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Without more information you will receive low quality responses like this: Create a VBA for your button that goes through your data and tally the cells in your summary table, OR create a pivot of your data and have button refresh the pivot...

Comment: Hi @Michael Bodenstein,, I can suggest you non VBA solution (formula based method),, if this works for you then [edit] your post & add line that Non VBA method will work also.

Comment: **Cont,,** also unable to get that how u r getting Total `5` & Col Total `2, 1, 1, 1` ,, since column totals are `2, 1, 2, 2` = `7` !!

Comment: Hi @ Rajesh, The column number and totals would just be sum (Would update automatically, every time a new entry is added. The totals are also incorrect as the fomulae I used did not update correctly.